# Overwriting item in list instead of creating new one

Tags: list, custom-list, splistitem

It's activated on button click event. Problem is that it's not creating another item in the list, but it is overwriting the current item, so there is always 1 item, instead of creating item on each click on the button, any idea how to fix it ?

```
string strDocName = "excel.xlsx";

        using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList test = oWeb.GetList("/Lists/PermissionImportLog");
                var testing = test.Fields;
                using (FileStream fs = (new FileInfo(@"C:\test\test2.xlsx")).OpenRead())
                {
                    SPList list = oWeb.GetList("/Lists/PermissionImportLog");

                    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
                    ht.Add("Created", DateTime.Now);
                    ht.Add("Permissionurl", oWeb.Url);

                    SPFile destfile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(strDocName, fs, ht, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: change the filename.

Comment: @DerekGusoff, ye I just checked this, but is there a option to allow the upload of a file with same name and create a new item in the list instead of overwriting this with the same file name?

Comment: OK, so if you go to /Lists/PermissionImportLog/excel.xlsx, which document will load?

Comment: @DerekGusoff the first one, but the strange thing in modified column it is said it is modified just now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file path can by definition only point to one document, it's like an address. Suppose you mail a letter to a certain address, and there are two homes with that address. Where does the mail carrier deliver the letter?

So your documents need unique file names.

The setting "overwrite existing files", if left unchecked, will simply fail if you try to upload duplicates.